# update two divs with one AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I'm using AJAX with struts1.x, In my application once select the first select item then second select item will be updated using AJAX. Once i select the second select item it will display the result using AJAX..
Now If the user selects different item of first select items, Then i have to display updated result in Second select items and disappear the previous result caused by second selected item.
Eg. select Country: India
    select State: Delhi
  Delhi Information will be printed here...
        Ajax response

```
document.getElementById("processStates").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;  

document.getElementById("StateInfoDisplay").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;  


  select country:<select name="countryName"
onchange="showStates(this.value);">  

<span id="processStates"> <select
name="stateName" onchange="showStateInfo(this.value);">  

<div id="StateInfoDisplay"></div>
```

i'm able to implement this. But new requiremetn came.. As per this i have to disappear state information and show states list once he selects some other state.

Next once user select Country as : USA 
I have to display all the states of USA and disappear the delhi information.
How to do it?
I'm using only javascript...not jquery..

Laxman Chowdary

Comment: You should post some of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo-code for county click handler:

```
if (selectedCountry != previousCountry) {
   states.clear()
   states.reload(selectedCountry)
}
```

You can do pretty much anything you want in handler - why stop at 2 divs? Rewrite entire page or whatever. If you have some specific problem, post it with your code.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not posted your code. I will give a general view.

On selecting country you have do a ajax call and get list of cities related to that country from db or where ever you are storing and populate it.

After that if user select city you have do one more ajax call will country and city to db get details of city from table.

To disappear the old data,  onchange of country or city you can make element empty

`$(selector).empty()` (basically on every country or city ajax call you will have to do it).